# Efficiently find mapping

Tags: sql, database, algorithm

Assume that we have two data sets A, B that have m to n relationship.

A = { k1, k2, k3 .... kn}
B = { g1, g2, g3..........gn}

All the elements in both the sets are alphanumeric.
Now, tuples one each from Set A and Set B are stored in a table T.

for ex :-
(k1, g2)
(k2, g4)
(k1, g3)
(k4, g2)
...
...
..
(kn, gm)

The challenge is to find out what 'm' elements in set A map to what 'n' elements in set B in the most efficient way.

For ex, let's say we have the below tuples,

(k1, g1)
(k1, g2)
(k3, g1)
(k3, g2)
(k5, g1)
(k5, g2)

the o/p I need is (k1, k3, k5) -> (g1, g2).

As the mapping is m to n, a simple select won' t work.  Please let me know if you need further clarifications

Since this information is already in database, I would prefer if we can get to this with some SQL.

Help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: not sure how the table is storing the tuples or if i'm understanding correctly, but, don't you already have that information? if there is a table with the tuples, say, tuple_table with tuples (kn, gm), and you want which k element (coming from set A) maps to which g element (coming from set B) wouldn't a simple select on the tuple_table do it?

Comment: Thanks for taking interest. Updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can often solve problems like this by using an aggregate, and a group by clause.

For example, if your table name is T then:

```
select T.item1, concat(T.item2, ", ") from T group by T.item1
```

Gives you which item1 maps to item 2. THen do it again switching item1 and item 2 around to find which item2 maps to item1.

Comment: Thanks Charles. I use MS SQL 2008 and I don't seem to find 'Concat' function. Am I missing something or do we have any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi MnM, I'm not sure how to do it in MS SQL, apparently string concat is not built in, so you have to write your own function. have a look at this link http://forums.aspfree.com/microsoft-sql-server-14/sql-aggregate-function-that-combines-like-concat-73073.html

Comment: Thanks Charles. I created a UDF.                                http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131056.aspx http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/owconcatenate.aspx                   I figured it might be easier to maintain if we keep the logic in code than to write it in SQL.